# I have a clock ticking when click start and stop made by ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a timer that work authomatically.But I want to add new feature to it. When I click it it should stop,when I click second time it should work.I used componentWillMount to create it.But it have some problems that I can not solve.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { date: new Date(), status: true };
    this.handleStatus = this.handleStatus.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.status) {
      const oneSecond = 1000;
      this.clear = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({ date: new Date() });
      }, oneSecond);
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (!this.state.status) {
      clearInterval(this.clear);
    }
  }

  handleStatus() {
    this.setState({ status: !this.state.status });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.status);
    return (
      <div className="fs-5 fw-bold text-primary">
        {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}
        <br />
        <button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={this.handleStatus}>
          Tikla
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Clock;
```

Comment: "have some problems that I can not solve." Please specify exactly which

Comment: `componentWillMount` is deprecated. And since you appear to be clearing the interval in it, I assume you meant to use `componentWillUnmount`?

Comment: Why did not you call ``clearInterval(this.clear);`` in ``handleStatus()`` function

Comment: @mplungjan when i click it is not stop.And when clicking second time it is not working

Comment: @EtsukoSusui I used it inside handleStatus() but when clicking it is stopping.But when clicking second time is it not start ticking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this.

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.status) {
      const oneSecond = 1000;
      this.clear = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({ date: new Date() });
      }, oneSecond);
    }
  }


  handleStatus() {
    if(this.state.status){
      clearInterval(this.clear);
    }
    else{
      const oneSecond = 1000;
      this.clear = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({ date: new Date() });
      }, oneSecond);
    }
    this.setState({ status: !this.state.status });
  }
```

You can confrim here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-cdn-lpntx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: ` this.clear = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({ date: new Date() });
      }, oneSecond);` used two times.

Comment: so we dont need componentWillMount anymore

Comment: The ``componentWillMount`` method is called right before a component mounts or the render method is called.